# Application of the axiom of choice

Tags: real-analysis, axiom-of-choice

I would like to prove the following statement.

If $A$ is a bounded, infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then there is an element $a \in A$ such that $A-\{a\}$ contains a sequence which converges to $a$.

I found this statement in an introductory course in logic which suggested to use the axiom of choice.

My approach: First I would like to find a non-isolated point in $A$, let's call it $a$. It seems that such a point must exist since only finitely many isolated points fit in the bounded region (I guess). Afterwards, we can choose (with the axiom of choice) a point in every interval around $a$ with the length of the interval going to zero. The sequence of those points has to converge to $a$.

Comment: The assertion as stated is false. Look at the fractions $1/n$. The only limit point is $0$, which is not in the set.

Comment: And what happens if we add the condition that $A$ has to be closed?

Comment: Then the modified statement becomes true.

Comment: To add the last comment by @Andre, it becomes true without the axiom of choice as well. I suspect, however, that the question was that if $A$ is bounded and infinite, then there is some $a\in\Bbb R$ such that there is a sequence in $A\setminus\{a\}$ converging to $a$.

Comment: I agree that even if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ was not *written*, it was *intended*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your application of the axiom of choice is generally right, but the "fine print" is wrong. But this doesn't mean that you got a sequence, because you have $2^{\aleph_0}$ intervals around $a$.

Instead you want to choose from the sets $(a-\frac1n,a+\frac1n)\cap A$, or something like that. Because a sequence is a function from $\Bbb N$ into $A$. So you need to be able to tell which element is the first, second, and so on. You also want them to be from $A$, rather than just from an interval around $a$.

This would also be a good time to indicate that the axiom of choice is necessary here, and it is consistent without the axiom of choice that there is a set of real numbers $D$ which has no isolated points, but every convergent sequence of elements of $D$ is eventually constant. In that case picking any $d\in D$ we have that $D\setminus\{d\}$ contains no sequence converging to $d$.

Comment: The way you described how to chose the intervals was actually what I meant. I'm still having difficulties understanding how you can chose a non-isolated point. Your last paragraph seems interesting. Can you give some more info about that? I don't understand what you are trying to say since such a $D$ cannot be bounded and infinite.

Comment: About the last part, well the details might be a bit too much right now. But they do exist on this site. Keyword term for that would be "Dedekind-finite". Note what Andre wrote below your answer.